# Using string SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string

I am getting the following error.

> Message = "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.\r\nIncorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

I have the following sql string query.

```
  private const string QueryString =
                                        "SELECT DISTINCT "

                             + " Person.[PersObjId]"
                             + ",Person.[PtObjId]"                                 
                             + ",MSN.[PersObjId]"
                             + ",MSN.[ExtrnId]  AS '" + MSNumber + "'"
                             + ",HlthProfMstrV.[RptName]  AS '" + ItemName + "'"
                             + ",HlthProfMstrV.[ItemStsId]  AS '" + ItemId + "'"

                             + "FROM [dbt1].[Person]"
                             + "join"
                             + "    ( "
                             + "    SELECT "
                             + "     PersIdRptV.PersObjId"
                             + "    , PersIdRptV.ExtrnId"
                             + "    FROM"
                             + "    dbt1.PersIdRptV"
                             + "    join dbt1.IdIssMstrV on PersIdRptV.IdIssObjId = IdIssMstrV.IdIssObjId"
                             + "    WHERE"
                             + "        PersIdRptV.TypeId = 5"
                             + "    and"
                             + "        PersIdRptV.StpDate is NULL"        
                             + "    ) AS MSN on dbt1.Person.PersObjId = MSN.PersObjId"
                             + "left join dbt1.HlthProfMstrV on Person.PCPHlthProfObjId = HlthProfMstrV.HlthProfObjId"
                             + " " + "WHERE" + " "
                             + "Person.[ExpressId] =12"                  
                             + "   and" + " "
                             + "Person.[StnTst] = 'Actv' "             
                             + " and" + " "
                             + "MSN.[ExtrnId] = @MSN ";
```

I think this error is occuring when I am getting the first join result where I assign the result set to "MSN". I tried taking out the AS from AS MSN and I get another error saying the following:

> Message = "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'MSN'.\r\nIncorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'MSN'."

I been looking at this for few hours. I am sure its something simple I am missing. Help appreciated!

Comment: Why are using variables as aliases for your column names? Something seems very strange here.

Comment: it seems that you don't have your @MSN variable created

Comment: Why are you tagging MySQL and sql-server please tag the correct database in use... looking to your code your are using sql-server.

Comment: make print QueryString, it should help to locale error

Comment: @Zinov how would i go about creating MSN variable created here ?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ I think you need to give the value directly on your case .....MSN.[ExtrnId] = (here put a variable create on the outside scope); just concatenate the value

Comment: Lol I am not sure why people are downvoting my question...

Comment: @Zinov im going to try that right now

Comment: Print out your query string and then copy that into the query window to see where your syntax errors are. There are a lot of closed spaces between lines that would cause you the syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a space between last column alias and `From` keyword:

```
+ ",HlthProfMstrV.[ItemStsId]  AS '" + ItemId + "'"

+ " FROM [dbt1].[Person]"
```

Comment: I did that. But I am getting same result

Comment: You have lots of spaces missing try to dump this string sql in console and run that query. Fix errors and keep spaces between keywords and literals.

Answer (score 2):

Space missing before person and join

```
                         + "FROM [dbt1].[Person]"
                         + " join"   --> Added space before join
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ "MSN.[ExtrnID] = '" + @MSN + "'"
```